# German RegEx-dictionary

Tags: dictionary

I'm looking for something like this: http://www.visca.com/regexdict/, but for the German language.
does anyone know of a website, or application, that provides this functionality?
I've tried Langenscheidt, Duden, and worder.cat; the former two don't provide this functionality, the latter only provides me with up to 1200 words, and even then only a limited number of different characters, which just doesn't cut it.

The reason I need RegEx, is I'm programming a school project (Hangman), and I'd like to add as many words as I can find, in four different levels.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Ispell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ispell) has dictionaries that (in the uncompressed form) consist of text files where each line contains a word, together with rule markers to generate affix forms if you need them. Here's the [German one (new spelling)](https://www.j3e.de/ispell/igerman98/) with 94210 words.

You can use standard programs like `grep`, or whatever library your programming language provides, to search in this file for regular expressions.

You may need to convert the umlaut markings to your encoding (utf-8, or whatever you use). Again, this can easily be done with standard programs (e.g. `sed`, or `perl`).

Answer (score 5):

[Aspell](http://aspell.net/) provides command-line utilities that spit out its word list, e.g.:

```
aspell -l de dump master | aspell -l de expand
```

will give you a list of all 364 thousand German words it considers correct.